# Appending to query string with everything intact

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I tried the below. That doesn't seem to work.

If the referrer has the string google.com, I want the rewrite rule to trigger, and preserve the existing query string and just append the referrer to the end of the query string

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .*google.com.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ^(.*)$referrer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [QSA]
```

I'm sure something in my rewriterule is wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

This should be better for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)referrer=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?referrer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you but that gives me an error.

[Sun Jul 02 23:03:59.584674 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 12795] [client 192.168.1.97:51574] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: https://sites.google.com/site/

Comment: To add more information, I am using mod_proxy to proxy /sample to /sample on tomcat running on the same machine. my incoming request is /sample/hello.jsp....I want the final request to be /sample/hello.jsp?referrer=%{HTTP_REFERER}

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add a condition to prevent it looping.

Comment: Thank you. I also needed an external redirect flag. Else it wasn't doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} google\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    !^referrer=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?referrer=%{HTTP_REFERER} [L,R,QSA]
```

I needed to add a condition that if there is already a referrer query string parameter, don't append it. Else I was getting an infinite loop.

And I needed a external Redirect flag. Else it was not redirecting.